# how to get access to ruby on rails database with coffeescript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

This one is simple. lets say i have a model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :author, :content, :title
end
```

and i want to get instance variables of this class with coffeescript, put those into an array, and work on them. Is there any special method for this out there?

Comment: Some less generic example?

Comment: i dont think there is really need for this, all i need is information how to get Post.scoped.where(id == 2) into coffescript variable and thats it

Comment: There is need as there are million ways to do so.

Comment: i dont know what to tell you,  my real life issue isnt really more complicated than what i gave you:/

Comment: Come on. You write a post model, so this is some kind of blog? Simply describe your app! :)

Comment: yup, a blog app, and while making a new post, i want to give user ability to use older posts information. so i let them choose post from select input, get this post id, and then, basing on id, i need to get post object which has this specific id:)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33689/discussion-between-kuba-polaczek-and-michael-szyndel)

Answer (score 0):

Highly debatable but I'd advise you to [use gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) as a quick setup.
It's even described in [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript).

Later you'd rather do ajax calls.